# Eigenstates for quantized oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, discrete

Hi I am new to solid state physics and am reviewing a prior knowledge section and would like some clarification. The following appeared in the course notes:

[image]

From my understanding, Eigenstates are only eigenstates when associated with the appropriate operator. Are the terms Eigenfunction and Eigenstate analogous? I understand the concept of Eigenfunctions such as e^(3x) but am having a hard time matching the terminology to the physics and so would be grateful for some help <3

Comment: [Quantum harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator).

Comment: cheers I will check this out!

Comment: Have you taken a quantum mechanics course?

Comment: Yes I have but am undergrad and revising it for the first time for upcoming exams. Any useful resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are eigenfunctions, eigenstates and eigenkets analogous terms? On a referenced wiki page it states this but on other websites it refers to 'Hilbert space'

Comment: @HarryJCritchfield eigenfunctions, eigenstates, and eigenkets are essentially equivalent, but Hilbert space is not: Hilbert space is the vector space consisting of *all* wavefunctions/states/kets, not just the set of *eigen*-functions/states/kets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term eigenfunction and eigenkets are as different as kets and wave function, or say matrices and operators, i.e to say they essentially have the same content, but just appear different in presentation(A fancy way to say this is to say that they are isomorphic). Recall that you could represent a Hermitian Operator  by a matrix.Same goes in this case, eigekets or kets in general have representations as wave functions.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Ok so my next question is in what context are the different presentations more useful? When would someone decide to use an eigenket rather than an eigenfunction? Are there some examples I could read up on? Cheers

Comment: When you want to solve differential equations(Schrodinger eqn, for instance) visualise the probability amplitudes, you do the wave function thing. Ket vectors are abstract, however you can associate to each ket a wave function. Recall from classical Mechanics you could do projections of a vector along x, y, z axis. Wavefunction is just like that, the projection of a state vector along the eigenkets. For example consider a system with a definite position, the corresponding wave function is the dirac delta, I. E only the projection along a particular eigenket has value, but the others are 0.

Comment: Please not that the explanation that I gave you in the comments was meant to aid your understanding, it was, however, not a completely precise answer, for that you need to refer to a good book, I recommend, the book called "A Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics" authored by John. S. Townsend.  For a bit more advanced treatment, refer to J. J. Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: Thanks for all the help greatly appreciated whilst my uni lecturers are ignoring emails!

Comment: Do remember again, the explanation given to you in the comments is only approximately true, I did so because I though it might not be a great idea to give you a sophisticated/abstract answer at this point of your learning, you should refer to good books, you should do that.